# React Hooks + Mobx => Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx

I have a React Native App,
Here i use mobx ("mobx-react": "^6.1.8") and react hooks.

i get the error: 
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

## Stores index.js

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import UserStore from "./UserStore";
import SettingsStore from "./SettingsStore";


const useStore = () => {
  return {
    UserStore: useContext(UserStore),
    SettingsStore: useContext(SettingsStore),
  };
};

export default useStore;
```

## helper.js OLD

```
    import React from "react";
    import useStores from "../stores";

    export const useLoadAsyncProfileDependencies = userID => {
  const { ExamsStore, UserStore, CTAStore, AnswersStore } = useStores();
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [ctas, setCtas] = useState([]);
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userID) {
      (async () => {
        const user = await UserStore.initUser();
        UserStore.user = user;
        setUser(user);
      })();
      (async () => {
        const ctas = await CTAStore.getAllCTAS(userID);
        CTAStore.ctas = ctas;
        setCtas(ctas);
      })();
      (async () => {
        const answers = await AnswersStore.getAllAnswers(userID);
        UserStore.user.answers = answers.items;
        AnswersStore.answers = answers.items;
        ExamsStore.initExams(answers.items);
        setAnswers(answers.items);
      })();
    }
  }, [userID]);
};
```

## Screen

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Dimensions,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp
} from "react-native-responsive-screen";

import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import useStores from "../../stores";
import { useLoadAsyncProfileDependencies } from "../../helper/app";
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;

export default observer(({ navigation }) => {
  const {
    UserStore,
    ExamsStore,
    CTAStore,
    InternetConnectionStore
  } = useStores();
  const scrollViewRef = useRef();

  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (InternetConnectionStore.isOffline) {
      return;
    }
    Tracking.trackEvent("opensScreen", { name: "Challenges" });
    useLoadAsyncProfileDependencies(UserStore.userID);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      CTAStore.popBadget(BadgetNames.ChallengesTab);
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  async function refresh() {
    const user = await UserStore.initUser(); //wird das gebarucht?
    useLoadAsyncProfileDependencies(UserStore.userID);
    if (user) {
      InternetConnectionStore.isOffline = false;
    }
  }

  const name = UserStore.name;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} forceInset={{ top: "always" }}>

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
});
```

so now, when i call the useLoadAsyncProfileDependencies function, i get this error.

The Problem is that i call useStores in helper.js

so when i pass the Stores from the Screen to the helper it is working.

```
export const loadAsyncProfileDependencies = async ({
  ExamsStore,
  UserStore,
  CTAStore,
  AnswersStore
}) => {
  const userID = UserStore.userID;
  if (userID) {
    UserStore.initUser().then(user => {
      UserStore.user = user;
    });
    CTAStore.getAllCTAS(userID).then(ctas => {
      console.log("test", ctas);
      CTAStore.ctas = ctas;
    });
    AnswersStore.getAllAnswers(userID).then(answers => {
      AnswersStore.answers = answers.items;
      ExamsStore.initExams(answers.items);
    });
  }
};
```

Is there a better way? instead passing the Stores. 
So that i can use this function in functions?

Comment: How are you calling `useLoadAsyncProfileDependencies`? This tends to happen when invoking a hook from an event handler, rather than during render.

Comment: First line in a component function.

Comment: Const someComponent = () => {
useLoadAsyncProfileDeps...
}

Comment: updated the Code in Root Post

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you can only use hooks inside the root of a functional component, and your `useLoadAsyncProfileDependencies` is technically a custom hook so you cant use it inside a class component.

https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

---

EDIT: Well after showing the code for app.js, as mentioned, hook calls can only be done top level from a function component or the root of a custom hook. You need to rewire your code to use custom hooks.

SEE THIS: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

1. You should return the value for `_handleAppStateChange` so your `useEffect`'s the value as a depdendency in your root component would work properly as intended which is should run only if value has changed. You also need to rewrite that as a custom hook so you can call hooks inside.
2. `doTasksEveryTimeWhenAppWillOpenFromBackgorund` and `doTasksEveryTimeWhenAppGoesToBackgorund` should also be written as a custom hook so you can call `useLoadAsyncProfileDependencies` inside.
3. write those hooks in a functional way so you are isolating specific tasks and chain hooks as you wish without violiating the rules of hooks. Something like this:

```js
const useGetMyData = (params) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const apiData = await myApiCall(params)
            setData(apiData)
        })()
    }, [params])

    return data
}
```

Then you can call that custom hook as you wish without violation like:

```js
const useShouldGetData = (should, params) => {
    if (should) {
        return useGetMyData()
    }

    return null
}

const myApp = () => {
    const myData = useShouldGetData(true, {id: 1})

    return (
        <div>
            {JSON.stringify(myData)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: It’s not a class. App.js and navigator are function components

Comment: then can you show us the code for those? We can't really get anywhere with what we have right now.

Comment: i updated the question. Thanks a lot for your help.